# Composer - conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability

Tags: php, composer-php

I'trying to install Twilio package but getting this error.

```
root@5aa8b298d8f2:/var/www# composer require aloha/twilio

Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Using version ^4.0 for aloha/twilio
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package aws/aws-sdk-php (installed at 3.154.1, required as 3.0) is satisfiable by aws/aws-sdk-php[3.154.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 1.0.28 requires aws/aws-sdk-php ^3.20.0 -> satisfiable by aws/aws-sdk-php[3.100.0, 3.100.1, 3.100.2, 3.100.3, 3.100.4, 3.100.5, 3.100.6, 3.100.7, 3.100.8, 3.100.9, 3.101.0, 3.101.1, 3.102.0, 3.102.1, 3.103.0, 3.103.1, 3.103.2, 3.104.0, 3.104.1, 3.105.0, 3.106.0, 3.106.1, 3.107.0, 3.107.1, 3.107.2, 3.107.3, 3.107.4, 3.107.5, 3.107.6, 3.107.7, 3.107.8, 3.108.0, 3.108.1, 3.108.2, 3.108.3, 3.108.4, 3.108.5, 3.108.6, 3.109.0, 3.109.1, 3.109.2, 3.109.3, 3.109.4, 3.109.5, 3.109.6, 3.109.7, 3.109.8, 3.110.0, 3.110.1, 3.110.10, 3.110.11, 3.110.2, 3.110.3, 3.110.4, 3.110.5, 3.110.6, 3.110.7, 3.110.8, 3.110.9, 3.111.0, 3.111.1, 3.111.2, 3.112.0, 3.112.1, 3.112.10, 3.112.11, 3.112.12, 3.112.13, 3.112.14, 3.112.15, 3.112.16, 3.112.17, 3.112.18, 3.112.19, 3.112.2, 3.112.20, 3.112.21, 3.112.22, 3.112.23, 3.112.24, 3.112.25, 3.112.26, 3.112.27, 3.112.28, 3.112.29, 3.112.3, 3.112.30, 3.112.31, 3.112.32, 3.112.33, 3.112.34, 3.112.35, 3.112.4, 3.112.5, 3.112.6, 3.112.7, 3.112.8, 3.112.9, 3.113.0, 3.114.0, 3.114.1, 3.115.0, 3.115.1, 3.115.2, 3.116.0, 3.117.0, 3.117.1, 3.117.2, 3.118.0, 3.119.0, 3.120.0, 3.121.0, 3.121.1, 3.122.0, 3.123.0, 3.124.0, 3.125.0, 3.126.0, 3.127.0, 3.128.0, 3.128.1, 3.128.2, 3.128.3, 3.128.4, 3.129.0, 3.129.1, 3.129.2, 3.129.3, 3.130.0, 3.130.1, 3.130.2, 3.130.3, 3.131.0, 3.132.0, 3.132.1, 3.132.2, 3.132.3, 3.132.4, 3.132.5, 3.133.0, 3.133.1, 3.133.10, 3.133.11, 3.133.12, 3.133.13, 3.133.14, 3.133.15, 3.133.16, 3.133.17, 3.133.18, 3.133.19, 3.133.2, 3.133.20, 3.133.21, 3.133.22, 3.133.23, 3.133.24, 3.133.25, 3.133.26, 3.133.27, 3.133.28, 3.133.29, 3.133.3, 3.133.30, 3.133.31, 3.133.32, 3.133.33, 3.133.34, 3.133.35, 3.133.36, 3.133.37, 3.133.38, 3.133.39, 3.133.4, 3.133.40, 3.133.41, 3.133.42, 3.133.43, 3.133.44, 3.133.45, 3.133.46, 3.133.47, 3.133.5, 3.133.6, 3.133.7, 3.133.8, 3.133.9, 3.134.0, 3.134.1, 3.134.2, 3.134.3, 3.134.4, 3.134.5, 3.134.6, 3.134.7, 3.134.8, 3.135.0, 3.135.1, 3.135.2, 3.135.3, 3.135.4, 3.135.5, 3.135.6, 3.136.0, 3.137.0, 3.137.1, 3.137.2, 3.137.3, 3.137.4, 3.137.5, 3.137.6, 3.137.7, 3.137.8, 3.138.0, 3.138.1, 3.138.10, 3.138.2, 3.138.3, 3.138.4, 3.138.5, 3.138.6, 3.138.7, 3.138.8, 3.138.9, 3.139.0, 3.139.1, 3.140.0, 3.140.1, 3.140.2, 3.140.3, 3.140.4, 3.141.0, 3.142.0, 3.142.1, 3.142.2, 3.142.3, 3.142.4, 3.142.5, 3.142.6, 3.142.7, 3.142.8, 3.143.0, 3.143.1, 3.143.2, 3.144.0, 3.144.1, 3.144.2, 3.145.0, 3.145.1, 3.145.2, 3.145.3, 3.145.4, 3.146.0, 3.147.0, 3.147.1, 3.147.10, 3.147.11, 3.147.12, 3.147.13, 3.147.14, 3.147.2, 3.147.3, 3.147.4, 3.147.5, 3.147.6, 3.147.7, 3.147.8, 3.147.9, 3.148.0, 3.148.1, 3.148.2, 3.148.3, 3.149.0, 3.149.1, 3.149.2, 3.150.0, 3.150.1, 3.150.2, 3.150.3, 3.151.0, 3.151.1, 3.151.2, 3.151.3, 3.151.4, 3.151.5, 3.151.6, 3.152.0, 3.152.1, 3.153.0, 3.154.0, 3.154.1, 3.154.2, 3.154.3, 3.154.4, 3.154.5, 3.154.6, 3.154.7, 3.20.0, 3.20.1, 3.20.10, 3.20.11, 3.20.12, 3.20.13, 3.20.14, 3.20.15, 3.20.16, 3.20.2, 3.20.3, 3.20.4, 3.20.5, 3.20.6, 3.20.7, 3.20.8, 3.20.9, 3.21.0, 3.21.1, 3.21.2, 3.21.3, 3.21.4, 3.21.5, 3.21.6, 3.22.0, 3.22.1, 3.22.10, 3.22.11, 3.22.2, 3.22.3, 3.22.4, 3.22.5, 3.22.6, 3.22.7, 3.22.8, 3.22.9, 3.23.0, 3.23.1, 3.23.2, 3.23.3, 3.24.0, 3.24.1, 3.24.2, 3.24.3, 3.24.4, 3.24.5, 3.24.6, 3.24.7, 3.24.8, 3.24.9, 3.25.0, 3.25.1, 3.25.2, 3.25.3, 3.25.4, 3.25.5, 3.25.6, 3.25.7, 3.25.8, 3.26.0, 3.26.1, 3.26.2, 3.26.3, 3.26.4, 3.26.5, 3.27.0, 3.27.1, 3.27.2, 3.27.3, 3.27.4, 3.27.5, 3.28.0, 3.28.1, 3.28.10, 3.28.2, 3.28.3, 3.28.4, 3.28.5, 3.28.6, 3.28.7, 3.28.8, 3.28.9, 3.29.0, 3.29.1, 3.29.2, 3.29.3, 3.29.4, 3.29.5, 3.29.6, 3.29.7, 3.29.8, 3.29.9, 3.30.0, 3.30.1, 3.30.2, 3.30.3, 3.30.4, 3.31.0, 3.31.1, 3.31.10, 3.31.2, 3.31.3, 3.31.4, 3.31.5, 3.31.6, 3.31.7, 3.31.8, 3.31.9, 3.32.0, 3.32.1, 3.32.2, 3.32.3, 3.32.4, 3.32.5, 3.32.6, 3.32.7, 3.33.0, 3.33.1, 3.33.2, 3.33.3, 3.33.4, 3.34.0, 3.34.1, 3.34.2, 3.35.0, 3.35.1, 3.35.2, 3.35.3, 3.36.0, 3.36.1, 3.36.10, 3.36.11, 3.36.12, 3.36.13, 3.36.14, 3.36.15, 3.36.16, 3.36.17, 3.36.18, 3.36.19, 3.36.2, 3.36.20, 3.36.21, 3.36.22, 3.36.23, 3.36.24, 3.36.25, 3.36.26, 3.36.27, 3.36.28, 3.36.29, 3.36.3, 3.36.30, 3.36.31, 3.36.32, 3.36.33, 3.36.34, 3.36.35, 3.36.36, 3.36.37, 3.36.4, 3.36.5, 3.36.6, 3.36.7, 3.36.8, 3.36.9, 3.37.0, 3.37.1, 3.38.0, 3.38.1, 3.38.2, 3.38.3, 3.38.4, 3.38.5, 3.39.0, 3.39.1, 3.39.2, 3.40.0, 3.41.0, 3.42.0, 3.43.0, 3.44.0, 3.44.1, 3.44.2, 3.45.0, 3.45.1, 3.45.2, 3.45.3, 3.46.0, 3.47.0, 3.47.1, 3.48.0, 3.48.1, 3.48.10, 3.48.11, 3.48.12, 3.48.13, 3.48.14, 3.48.2, 3.48.3, 3.48.4, 3.48.5, 3.48.6, 3.48.7, 3.48.8, 3.48.9, 3.49.0, 3.49.1, 3.50.0, 3.51.0, 3.52.0, 3.52.1, 3.52.10, 3.52.11, 3.52.12, 3.52.13, 3.52.14, 3.52.15, 3.52.16, 3.52.17, 3.52.18, 3.52.19, 3.52.2, 3.52.20, 3.52.21, 3.52.22, 3.52.23, 3.52.24, 3.52.25, 3.52.26, 3.52.27, 3.52.28, 3.52.29, 3.52.3, 3.52.30, 3.52.31, 3.52.32, 3.52.33, 3.52.34, 3.52.35, 3.52.36, 3.52.4, 3.52.5, 3.52.6, 3.52.7, 3.52.8, 3.52.9, 3.53.0, 3.53.1, 3.53.2, 3.54.0, 3.54.1, 3.54.2, 3.54.3, 3.54.4, 3.54.5, 3.54.6, 3.55.0, 3.55.1, 3.55.10, 3.55.11, 3.55.12, 3.55.2, 3.55.3, 3.55.4, 3.55.5, 3.55.6, 3.55.7, 3.55.8, 3.55.9, 3.56.0, 3.56.1, 3.56.2, 3.56.3, 3.56.4, 3.56.5, 3.56.6, 3.57.0, 3.57.1, 3.58.0, 3.59.0, 3.60.0, 3.61.0, 3.61.1, 3.61.10, 3.61.2, 3.61.3, 3.61.4, 3.61.5, 3.61.6, 3.61.7, 3.61.8, 3.61.9, 3.62.0, 3.62.1, 3.62.10, 3.62.11, 3.62.12, 3.62.13, 3.62.14, 3.62.2, 3.62.3, 3.62.4, 3.62.5, 3.62.6, 3.62.7, 3.62.8, 3.62.9, 3.63.0, 3.63.1, 3.63.2, 3.63.3, 3.63.4, 3.63.5, 3.63.6, 3.63.7, 3.64.0, 3.64.1, 3.64.10, 3.64.11, 3.64.12, 3.64.13, 3.64.14, 3.64.15, 3.64.2, 3.64.3, 3.64.4, 3.64.5, 3.64.6, 3.64.7, 3.64.8, 3.64.9, 3.65.0, 3.65.1, 3.65.2, 3.66.0, 3.66.1, 3.66.2, 3.67.0, 3.67.1, 3.67.10, 3.67.11, 3.67.12, 3.67.13, 3.67.14, 3.67.15, 3.67.16, 3.67.17, 3.67.18, 3.67.19, 3.67.2, 3.67.20, 3.67.21, 3.67.22, 3.67.3, 3.67.4, 3.67.5, 3.67.6, 3.67.7, 3.67.8, 3.67.9, 3.68.0, 3.68.1, 3.69.0, 3.69.1, 3.69.10, 3.69.11, 3.69.12, 3.69.13, 3.69.14, 3.69.15, 3.69.16, 3.69.2, 3.69.3, 3.69.4, 3.69.5, 3.69.6, 3.69.7, 3.69.8, 3.69.9, 3.70.0, 3.70.1, 3.70.2, 3.70.3, 3.70.4, 3.71.0, 3.71.1, 3.71.2, 3.71.3, 3.71.4, 3.71.5, 3.71.6, 3.72.0, 3.72.1, 3.73.0, 3.74.0, 3.74.1, 3.75.0, 3.76.0, 3.77.0, 3.78.0, 3.79.0, 3.80.0, 3.80.1, 3.80.2, 3.80.3, 3.81.0, 3.81.1, 3.81.2, 3.81.3, 3.81.4, 3.81.5, 3.81.6, 3.81.7, 3.82.0, 3.82.1, 3.82.2, 3.82.3, 3.82.4, 3.82.5, 3.82.6, 3.83.0, 3.84.0, 3.85.0, 3.85.1, 3.85.2, 3.86.0, 3.86.1, 3.86.2, 3.86.3, 3.87.0, 3.87.1, 3.87.10, 3.87.11, 3.87.12, 3.87.13, 3.87.14, 3.87.15, 3.87.16, 3.87.17, 3.87.18, 3.87.19, 3.87.2, 3.87.20, 3.87.21, 3.87.22, 3.87.23, 3.87.3, 3.87.4, 3.87.5, 3.87.6, 3.87.7, 3.87.8, 3.87.9, 3.88.0, 3.88.1, 3.89.0, 3.89.1, 3.90.0, 3.90.1, 3.90.10, 3.90.11, 3.90.12, 3.90.13, 3.90.2, 3.90.3, 3.90.4, 3.90.5, 3.90.6, 3.90.7, 3.90.8, 3.90.9, 3.91.0, 3.91.1, 3.91.2, 3.91.3, 3.91.4, 3.91.5, 3.91.6, 3.92.0, 3.92.1, 3.92.2, 3.92.3, 3.92.4, 3.92.5, 3.93.0, 3.93.1, 3.93.10, 3.93.11, 3.93.12, 3.93.2, 3.93.3, 3.93.4, 3.93.5, 3.93.6, 3.93.7, 3.93.8, 3.93.9, 3.94.0, 3.94.1, 3.94.2, 3.94.3, 3.95.0, 3.96.0, 3.97.0, 3.98.0, 3.99.0, 3.99.1, 3.99.2, 3.99.3, 3.99.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 1.0.28 requires aws/aws-sdk-php ^3.20.0 -> satisfiable by aws/aws-sdk-php[3.100.0, 3.100.1, 3.100.2, 3.100.3, 3.100.4, 3.100.5, 3.100.6, 3.100.7, 3.100.8, 3.100.9, 3.101.0, 3.101.1, 3.102.0, 3.102.1, 3.103.0, 3.103.1, 3.103.2, 3.104.0, 3.104.1, 3.105.0, 3.106.0, 3.106.1, 3.107.0, 3.107.1, 3.107.2, 3.107.3, 3.107.4, 3.107.5, 3.107.6, 3.107.7, 3.107.8, 3.108.0, 3.108.1, 3.108.2, 3.108.3, 3.108.4, 3.108.5, 3.108.6, 3.109.0, 3.109.1, 3.109.2, 3.109.3, 3.109.4, 3.109.5, 3.109.6, 3.109.7, 3.109.8, 3.110.0, 3.110.1, 3.110.10, 3.110.11, 3.110.2, 3.110.3, 3.110.4, 3.110.5, 3.110.6, 3.110.7, 3.110.8, 3.110.9, 3.111.0, 3.111.1, 3.111.2, 3.112.0, 3.112.1, 3.112.10, 3.112.11, 3.112.12, 3.112.13, 3.112.14, 3.112.15, 3.112.16, 3.112.17, 3.112.18, 3.112.19, 3.112.2, 3.112.20, 3.112.21, 3.112.22, 3.112.23, 3.112.24, 3.112.25, 3.112.26, 3.112.27, 3.112.28, 3.112.29, 3.112.3, 3.112.30, 3.112.31, 3.112.32, 3.112.33, 3.112.34, 3.112.35, 3.112.4, 3.112.5, 3.112.6, 3.112.7, 3.112.8, 3.112.9, 3.113.0, 3.114.0, 3.114.1, 3.115.0, 3.115.1, 3.115.2, 3.116.0, 3.117.0, 3.117.1, 3.117.2, 3.118.0, 3.119.0, 3.120.0, 3.121.0, 3.121.1, 3.122.0, 3.123.0, 3.124.0, 3.125.0, 3.126.0, 3.127.0, 3.128.0, 3.128.1, 3.128.2, 3.128.3, 3.128.4, 3.129.0, 3.129.1, 3.129.2, 3.129.3, 3.130.0, 3.130.1, 3.130.2, 3.130.3, 3.131.0, 3.132.0, 3.132.1, 3.132.2, 3.132.3, 3.132.4, 3.132.5, 3.133.0, 3.133.1, 3.133.10, 3.133.11, 3.133.12, 3.133.13, 3.133.14, 3.133.15, 3.133.16, 3.133.17, 3.133.18, 3.133.19, 3.133.2, 3.133.20, 3.133.21, 3.133.22, 3.133.23, 3.133.24, 3.133.25, 3.133.26, 3.133.27, 3.133.28, 3.133.29, 3.133.3, 3.133.30, 3.133.31, 3.133.32, 3.133.33, 3.133.34, 3.133.35, 3.133.36, 3.133.37, 3.133.38, 3.133.39, 3.133.4, 3.133.40, 3.133.41, 3.133.42, 3.133.43, 3.133.44, 3.133.45, 3.133.46, 3.133.47, 3.133.5, 3.133.6, 3.133.7, 3.133.8, 3.133.9, 3.134.0, 3.134.1, 3.134.2, 3.134.3, 3.134.4, 3.134.5, 3.134.6, 3.134.7, 3.134.8, 3.135.0, 3.135.1, 3.135.2, 3.135.3, 3.135.4, 3.135.5, 3.135.6, 3.136.0, 3.137.0, 3.137.1, 3.137.2, 3.137.3, 3.137.4, 3.137.5, 3.137.6, 3.137.7, 3.137.8, 3.138.0, 3.138.1, 3.138.10, 3.138.2, 3.138.3, 3.138.4, 3.138.5, 3.138.6, 3.138.7, 3.138.8, 3.138.9, 3.139.0, 3.139.1, 3.140.0, 3.140.1, 3.140.2, 3.140.3, 3.140.4, 3.141.0, 3.142.0, 3.142.1, 3.142.2, 3.142.3, 3.142.4, 3.142.5, 3.142.6, 3.142.7, 3.142.8, 3.143.0, 3.143.1, 3.143.2, 3.144.0, 3.144.1, 3.144.2, 3.145.0, 3.145.1, 3.145.2, 3.145.3, 3.145.4, 3.146.0, 3.147.0, 3.147.1, 3.147.10, 3.147.11, 3.147.12, 3.147.13, 3.147.14, 3.147.2, 3.147.3, 3.147.4, 3.147.5, 3.147.6, 3.147.7, 3.147.8, 3.147.9, 3.148.0, 3.148.1, 3.148.2, 3.148.3, 3.149.0, 3.149.1, 3.149.2, 3.150.0, 3.150.1, 3.150.2, 3.150.3, 3.151.0, 3.151.1, 3.151.2, 3.151.3, 3.151.4, 3.151.5, 3.151.6, 3.152.0, 3.152.1, 3.153.0, 3.154.0, 3.154.1, 3.154.2, 3.154.3, 3.154.4, 3.154.5, 3.154.6, 3.154.7, 3.20.0, 3.20.1, 3.20.10, 3.20.11, 3.20.12, 3.20.13, 3.20.14, 3.20.15, 3.20.16, 3.20.2, 3.20.3, 3.20.4, 3.20.5, 3.20.6, 3.20.7, 3.20.8, 3.20.9, 3.21.0, 3.21.1, 3.21.2, 3.21.3, 3.21.4, 3.21.5, 3.21.6, 3.22.0, 3.22.1, 3.22.10, 3.22.11, 3.22.2, 3.22.3, 3.22.4, 3.22.5, 3.22.6, 3.22.7, 3.22.8, 3.22.9, 3.23.0, 3.23.1, 3.23.2, 3.23.3, 3.24.0, 3.24.1, 3.24.2, 3.24.3, 3.24.4, 3.24.5, 3.24.6, 3.24.7, 3.24.8, 3.24.9, 3.25.0, 3.25.1, 3.25.2, 3.25.3, 3.25.4, 3.25.5, 3.25.6, 3.25.7, 3.25.8, 3.26.0, 3.26.1, 3.26.2, 3.26.3, 3.26.4, 3.26.5, 3.27.0, 3.27.1, 3.27.2, 3.27.3, 3.27.4, 3.27.5, 3.28.0, 3.28.1, 3.28.10, 3.28.2, 3.28.3, 3.28.4, 3.28.5, 3.28.6, 3.28.7, 3.28.8, 3.28.9, 3.29.0, 3.29.1, 3.29.2, 3.29.3, 3.29.4, 3.29.5, 3.29.6, 3.29.7, 3.29.8, 3.29.9, 3.30.0, 3.30.1, 3.30.2, 3.30.3, 3.30.4, 3.31.0, 3.31.1, 3.31.10, 3.31.2, 3.31.3, 3.31.4, 3.31.5, 3.31.6, 3.31.7, 3.31.8, 3.31.9, 3.32.0, 3.32.1, 3.32.2, 3.32.3, 3.32.4, 3.32.5, 3.32.6, 3.32.7, 3.33.0, 3.33.1, 3.33.2, 3.33.3, 3.33.4, 3.34.0, 3.34.1, 3.34.2, 3.35.0, 3.35.1, 3.35.2, 3.35.3, 3.36.0, 3.36.1, 3.36.10, 3.36.11, 3.36.12, 3.36.13, 3.36.14, 3.36.15, 3.36.16, 3.36.17, 3.36.18, 3.36.19, 3.36.2, 3.36.20, 3.36.21, 3.36.22, 3.36.23, 3.36.24, 3.36.25, 3.36.26, 3.36.27, 3.36.28, 3.36.29, 3.36.3, 3.36.30, 3.36.31, 3.36.32, 3.36.33, 3.36.34, 3.36.35, 3.36.36, 3.36.37, 3.36.4, 3.36.5, 3.36.6, 3.36.7, 3.36.8, 3.36.9, 3.37.0, 3.37.1, 3.38.0, 3.38.1, 3.38.2, 3.38.3, 3.38.4, 3.38.5, 3.39.0, 3.39.1, 3.39.2, 3.40.0, 3.41.0, 3.42.0, 3.43.0, 3.44.0, 3.44.1, 3.44.2, 3.45.0, 3.45.1, 3.45.2, 3.45.3, 3.46.0, 3.47.0, 3.47.1, 3.48.0, 3.48.1, 3.48.10, 3.48.11, 3.48.12, 3.48.13, 3.48.14, 3.48.2, 3.48.3, 3.48.4, 3.48.5, 3.48.6, 3.48.7, 3.48.8, 3.48.9, 3.49.0, 3.49.1, 3.50.0, 3.51.0, 3.52.0, 3.52.1, 3.52.10, 3.52.11, 3.52.12, 3.52.13, 3.52.14, 3.52.15, 3.52.16, 3.52.17, 3.52.18, 3.52.19, 3.52.2, 3.52.20, 3.52.21, 3.52.22, 3.52.23, 3.52.24, 3.52.25, 3.52.26, 3.52.27, 3.52.28, 3.52.29, 3.52.3, 3.52.30, 3.52.31, 3.52.32, 3.52.33, 3.52.34, 3.52.35, 3.52.36, 3.52.4, 3.52.5, 3.52.6, 3.52.7, 3.52.8, 3.52.9, 3.53.0, 3.53.1, 3.53.2, 3.54.0, 3.54.1, 3.54.2, 3.54.3, 3.54.4, 3.54.5, 3.54.6, 3.55.0, 3.55.1, 3.55.10, 3.55.11, 3.55.12, 3.55.2, 3.55.3, 3.55.4, 3.55.5, 3.55.6, 3.55.7, 3.55.8, 3.55.9, 3.56.0, 3.56.1, 3.56.2, 3.56.3, 3.56.4, 3.56.5, 3.56.6, 3.57.0, 3.57.1, 3.58.0, 3.59.0, 3.60.0, 3.61.0, 3.61.1, 3.61.10, 3.61.2, 3.61.3, 3.61.4, 3.61.5, 3.61.6, 3.61.7, 3.61.8, 3.61.9, 3.62.0, 3.62.1, 3.62.10, 3.62.11, 3.62.12, 3.62.13, 3.62.14, 3.62.2, 3.62.3, 3.62.4, 3.62.5, 3.62.6, 3.62.7, 3.62.8, 3.62.9, 3.63.0, 3.63.1, 3.63.2, 3.63.3, 3.63.4, 3.63.5, 3.63.6, 3.63.7, 3.64.0, 3.64.1, 3.64.10, 3.64.11, 3.64.12, 3.64.13, 3.64.14, 3.64.15, 3.64.2, 3.64.3, 3.64.4, 3.64.5, 3.64.6, 3.64.7, 3.64.8, 3.64.9, 3.65.0, 3.65.1, 3.65.2, 3.66.0, 3.66.1, 3.66.2, 3.67.0, 3.67.1, 3.67.10, 3.67.11, 3.67.12, 3.67.13, 3.67.14, 3.67.15, 3.67.16, 3.67.17, 3.67.18, 3.67.19, 3.67.2, 3.67.20, 3.67.21, 3.67.22, 3.67.3, 3.67.4, 3.67.5, 3.67.6, 3.67.7, 3.67.8, 3.67.9, 3.68.0, 3.68.1, 3.69.0, 3.69.1, 3.69.10, 3.69.11, 3.69.12, 3.69.13, 3.69.14, 3.69.15, 3.69.16, 3.69.2, 3.69.3, 3.69.4, 3.69.5, 3.69.6, 3.69.7, 3.69.8, 3.69.9, 3.70.0, 3.70.1, 3.70.2, 3.70.3, 3.70.4, 3.71.0, 3.71.1, 3.71.2, 3.71.3, 3.71.4, 3.71.5, 3.71.6, 3.72.0, 3.72.1, 3.73.0, 3.74.0, 3.74.1, 3.75.0, 3.76.0, 3.77.0, 3.78.0, 3.79.0, 3.80.0, 3.80.1, 3.80.2, 3.80.3, 3.81.0, 3.81.1, 3.81.2, 3.81.3, 3.81.4, 3.81.5, 3.81.6, 3.81.7, 3.82.0, 3.82.1, 3.82.2, 3.82.3, 3.82.4, 3.82.5, 3.82.6, 3.83.0, 3.84.0, 3.85.0, 3.85.1, 3.85.2, 3.86.0, 3.86.1, 3.86.2, 3.86.3, 3.87.0, 3.87.1, 3.87.10, 3.87.11, 3.87.12, 3.87.13, 3.87.14, 3.87.15, 3.87.16, 3.87.17, 3.87.18, 3.87.19, 3.87.2, 3.87.20, 3.87.21, 3.87.22, 3.87.23, 3.87.3, 3.87.4, 3.87.5, 3.87.6, 3.87.7, 3.87.8, 3.87.9, 3.88.0, 3.88.1, 3.89.0, 3.89.1, 3.90.0, 3.90.1, 3.90.10, 3.90.11, 3.90.12, 3.90.13, 3.90.2, 3.90.3, 3.90.4, 3.90.5, 3.90.6, 3.90.7, 3.90.8, 3.90.9, 3.91.0, 3.91.1, 3.91.2, 3.91.3, 3.91.4, 3.91.5, 3.91.6, 3.92.0, 3.92.1, 3.92.2, 3.92.3, 3.92.4, 3.92.5, 3.93.0, 3.93.1, 3.93.10, 3.93.11, 3.93.12, 3.93.2, 3.93.3, 3.93.4, 3.93.5, 3.93.6, 3.93.7, 3.93.8, 3.93.9, 3.94.0, 3.94.1, 3.94.2, 3.94.3, 3.95.0, 3.96.0, 3.97.0, 3.98.0, 3.99.0, 3.99.1, 3.99.2, 3.99.3, 3.99.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (installed at 1.0.28, required as ^1.0) -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[1.0.28].
```

What does it mean? It's not compatible?

How should I handle that?

Comment: Please share more details - how did you require the two packages given in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aloha/twilio` is not the problem.
You have a conflict with packages `aws/aws-sdk-php` and `league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`.